# E2E Testing- click on specific button

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, e2e-testing, nightwatch.js, e2e

I have a button, it looks like this in HTML form

```
<span class="v-btn__content">Create</span>
```

My E2E Test, I am trying to click that `Create` button

```
module.exports = {
    'My first test case'(browser) {
        browser

        .url('http://localhost:8080/#/')

        .waitForElementVisible('#app')
        .waitForElementVisible('#input-10')
        .waitForElementVisible('#input-13')
        .setValue('#input-10', 'jdoe@email.com')
        .setValue('#input-13', '**')
        .click('.v-btn__content')
        .assert.textContains('.v-toolbar__title','App')
        .waitForElementVisible('.v-data-footer__pagination')
        .waitForElementVisible('.v-btn__content')
        .assert.textContains('.v-btn__content','Create')
        .click('.v-btn__content','Create')  ❌
        
    }
}
```

I got

> ✖ Testing if element <.v-btn__content> contains text 'Create' in 5000ms - expected "contains text 'Create'" but got: "does not contain 'Create'" (5219ms)

Comment: Why the last click() receives 2 arguments and not one?

Comment: I was trying to be more specific with className (.v-btn__content) and also contain the text "Create"

Comment: From that error you got, it seems it failed on .assert.textContains('.v-btn__content','Create'), not on the click. Maybe try to remove that assertion. Also, you can try to target that button itself, but as I can see, it has already clicked on it. On the step where you did .setValue('#input-13', '**')

Answer (score 1):

I cannot confirm 100% that my guess is correct, but from my understanding, textContains would select a DOM element that you provide the selector for, and compare with the text you provided.
Though, in your example, your selector is a classname, which can be attributed to several elements, especially a generic one such as `v-btn__content`.

A potential fix could be to give your HTML button an id such as:
`<span id="create-content" class="v-btn__content">Create</span>`, and then replace the textContains selector by:

```
...
.assert.textContains('#create-content', 'Create')
...
```

Now again, if this is the error, then I am surprised that you did not get an error with `.assert.textContains('.v-toolbar__title','App')`, but this could be because textContains is smart enough to shorthand to a single element if only one exists in your page, which most likely is the case.

If this does not resolve it, happy to help further if you could provide a minimal codesandbox.